# Plotting Streamlines Maple

Tags: maple, fluid-dynamics

I wonder if anybody could help with this. I've been asked to plot the streamlines of the complex potential $\Omega(z)=Uz + \frac{m}{2\pi}ln(z)$ to which I get the stream function $\psi(r,\theta)=rUsin\theta + \frac{m}{2\pi}\theta$.

Hopefully that is correct, but I cannot seem to plot it using polar coords in Maple. I would like to plot a series of streamlines of $\psi = constant.$ Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can treat $\psi$ as a function of two variables. Is it enough plotting $\psi$?

Comment: Can't get the command to work - always comes up with an error. I converted back into cartesian coords and tried a contour plot, but doesn't look quite how I expected it would.

Comment: What is the domain of $z$? What will you do with $U$ and $m$? If we don't have them we cannot make any plots.

Comment: $U$ & $m$ are some constant, so I just set them to equal 1. $r > 0$ (I tried $0<r<10$), $0<\theta<2\pi$. Am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 [> with(plots):
    conformal(z+ln(z)/(2*Pi), z = -20*I .. 2+20*I);
```

[image]

And for $\psi$, I think you can consider it as a function of two variables and plot it by the following code:

```
 [> with(plots):
    implicitplot(r*sin(t)+t/(2*Pi), r = 0 .. 10, t = 0 .. 2*Pi);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly the sort of thing I was expecting. I didn't know about this function on Maple; a great help, thanks!

Comment: @BritMiller: I am glad I could help. :)

Comment: With the edit you have put, would you know how to sequence some plots so I could plot for example $\psi =0,1,2,3...$?

Comment: @BritMiller: See this [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/483847/8581). I could employ `seq` to find many curves.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks again - much appreciated.

Comment: @BritMiller: That's nothing my friend. :-)

Comment: @BabakS. Nice plots. Really miss you! Haletoon khoobe ishalla?

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi: Alhamdolleh Mahdi. Kamisarma khordam ine ke plot haye bala kami lar-zan rasm shodan. Khob shod ke didamet.

Comment: @BabakS. Ishalla zoodtar salamatitoon ro be dast biarin. Terme jadid ham ke dare shoroo mishe! Ye darse khoob ke kheili be Abstract Algebra nazdike ro mikham in term bardaram : Coding Theory. Manam khosh halam az didanetoon.

Comment: Maple to the rescue! +1